# How to replace text in HTML Node without disturbing other child nodes?

Tags: javascript, html

My structure is:

```
<th>0.12345<div id="someDiv"></div></th>
```

I need to replace 0.123456 with other text, without deleting div.
Using `innerHTML` and `innerText` kills all the th content.

I understand that I can use `substr()` to cut the innerHTML first and then reconstruct the full content, but is there the simplest way?

Comment: wrap that text in a `<span>` so you can work with it directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select TextNode object and reset its `nodeValue`. Now how to do it. You can start from the div, as you know it's id. Then you could get textNode with `previousSibling` property.

Something like this:

```js
document.querySelector('#someDiv').previousSibling.nodeValue = 'TEST'
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>0.12345 <div id="someDiv">div</div></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**UPD**. In case you want to *insert* new text node before div and support both scenarios you can do this:

```
var div = document.querySelector('#someDiv');

if (div.previousSibling) {
    div.previousSibling.nodeValue = 'TEST1';
}
else {
    div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', 'TEST2');

    // or if you want verbose
    // div.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode('TEST2'), div);
}
```

Comment: Sounds good! But what if I have `<th><div id="someDiv">div</div></th>`? How to insert my text before div?

Comment: @splash27 in that case you can use `innerHTML` like `innerHTML = "your text "  + innerHTML`

Comment: @JonP It's better to avoid using `innerHTML` like this, as it removes all the event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var th = document.getElementsByTagName('th')[0];
th.childNodes[0].textContent = "foo";
```

```html
<table><th>0.12345<div id="someDiv">somediv</div></th></table>
```

Unfortunately, jQuery does not give great support for text nodes, so you should grab it manually using `childNodes` or XPath.

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrap the content you need in a span tag and manipulate it directly for simplicity.

html:

```
<th>
    <span class="myValue">0.12345</span> 
    <div id="someDiv">div</div>
</th>
```

js:

```
$(".myValue").html("XXX");
```